# Finding groups of similar people

Tags: clustering, spss, survey

After asking 16 questions (yes or no) to 75 people I have a table of their answers coded like `00110011110101010` ('0'=no and '1'=yes). Now I would like to find groups of people who answered in the most similar way (ideally to find all possible groups with similitudes from 16/16 to 12/16).

How to do this in SPSS?

Comment: You might consider looking into cluster analysis.

Comment: Thanks! What I do next? I asked this thing here because I never used SPSS and statistics is not my field :)

Comment: If you get the answers as I(16) vector, then maybe get the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of these vectors, and group by the resulting value.

Comment: @Aksakal That will only give the number of `yes` responses in common. To find the number of common answers (considering both matching `no` responses and matching `yes` responses), it may be more appropriate to use [Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). In fact, @Lalala, you've already described the distance function of interest: the number of non-matching responses.

Comment: @Max, good point. SUM(NOT(XOR())) will catch matching ones and zeros.

Comment: I haven't used SPSS, but the documentation lists many possible [distance functions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fidh_clus.htm) that may be used in hierarchical clustering. It looks like the simple matching distance may be useful.

Comment: Please do not alter your question substantially after others have answered it: that potentially creates great confusion among readers and is unfair to those who have answered. If you have a distinct follow-up question, please post it as a new one (and feel free to include a link back to this one to maintain continuity). Please note, too, that questions about how to program or control a particular software application are not on topic here: see our [help] for links to other resources you can use to get answers to such questions.

Comment: "In brief, when you are in doubt about a question, don't migrate it, improve it"!  Here the improvement needed is to ask about appropriate clustering methods and then as a sub-question to ask for the answerer to provide information regarding how to do it in SPSS.  However, I suspect once you learn the right magic words you'll be able to search the SPSS help files and figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from cluster analysis, which would be best done by splitting the variable into their 16 parts, you could use a string similarity measure such as Levenshtein or Dice distance, both available via the Python extensions for Statistics.  But two-step or hierarchical clustering is probably the place to start.

Comment: Good idea. But Im a bit dummy for Python.
How do I split variables?